# How to determine whether the page is closed directly or through a jump on the a tag in the beforeunload callback

Tags: javascript, html

How to determine whether the page should be closed directly or redirected to another page in the beforeunload callback in a browser.

Comment: What is that you want to achieve? It is often better to ask the broader question "this is what I want to do, this is what I am doing" since there maybe better ways to do what you want to do.

Comment: I am working on the retention rate of a website, and I need to distinguish whether users are leaving the website or making a jump within the website.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting whether a web page is being closed directly or through a jump on an  tag within the beforeunload callback can be challenging due to limitations in the way browser events are handled.

You can create a flag on global space for click on  tag like this

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
  aTags[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    // Set a flag indicating that an <a> tag was clicked
    window.aTagClicked = true;
  });
}
```

use that variable in before unload but this is not fool proof due to race condition of setting the variable on global space and navigation being triggered by the browser.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
});
```

What you are trying to achieve can be done but it cannot be done perfectly.